# What's the difference between Channel shortening and time-domain equalizer

Tags: discrete-signals, equalization

I'm asking about the difference about channel shortening and time-domain equalization. I have checked on-line and tried to get something clear but I couldn't.

What I found is that channel shortening means almost  "Calculating the coefficients for DFE equalizer" But I couldn't also imagine that.

Could you please explain.

Thank you

Comment: By "time equalization" do you mean "time-domain equalization"? It would be good if you gave references where you found the terms you ask about. "Channel shortening" is clear but "time equalization" isn't.

Comment: @MattL. .. Yes It's time-domain equalization

Comment: @Eng.Badr it's really not the first time we ask you to cite your sources. :( This question is unclear without you telling us where you've found these terms.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's strange that you ask such questions like that !!!!   You don't know neither  what's the time-domain equalization  nor what's  the channel shortening ??   Dear,,  these concepts are the basic of communications eng. .. just google them and read .... !!!  .. So, again you downvoted !!  These terms are found everywhere dear.

Comment: Not discussing this with you. Cite your sources when writing "I found...". It's really not optional.

Comment: Hello .. OK .. here is the Time domain equalization: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8107486/ and here the channel shortening : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7296620/ ..  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,I agreed these terms are very common in communication engineering,

I was asking about channel shortening long time ago, and I got an answer telling me that channel shortening is just calculating the coefficients of the DFE. you can read the details in the below link

[Channel Shortening for underwater acoustic channel communication](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/channel-shortening-for-underwater-acoustic-channel-communication)

thanks

Comment: Thank you .  I got it, but I still search what's the difference between them ? why do we call sometimes channel shortening and another time TEQ ?